# Google Sheets: Conduct VLOOKUP on array stored in a different cell

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formula

I am trying to store a series of key/value pairs in a single cell in Google Sheets, then interrogate the array using formulae, such as VLOOKUP().

As an example, there is an array storing a series of key/value pairs: ​

```
{"keyA", "valueA"; "keyB", "valueB"; "keyC", "valueC"}
```

You can use VLOOKUP on this array if it is embedded in the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP("keyB",{"keyA","valueA";"keyB","valueB";"keyC","valueC"},2,FALSE)
```

which will return "valueB".

But if you store the array in a cell (eg B2) and refer to that cell in the formula, eg:

```
=VLOOKUP("keyB",B2,2,FALSE)
```

...you get a #REF! response with the detail: "Error. VLOOKUP evaluates to an out-of-bounds range."

Can anyone suggest a solution to this please?

Many thanks

Comment: Create a table (2 columns) with the keys in the first column and the values in the second. Then use this array as the vlookup range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `EVALUATE` formula in Spreadsheet.

The array expression is some kind of formula, in order to output a range of values, you have to put:

```
={"keyA", "valueA"; "keyB", "valueB"; "keyC", "valueC"}
```

You could then do `VLOOKUP` on the output.

---

However, you can parse it yourself with `SPLIT`

```
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B2,"^{""|""}$",),"""; """,FALSE)),""", """,FALSE))
```